# How would I grant user based Yammer REST API access to an ETL tool?

Tags: api, rest, yammer

I've an ETL tool that is capable of making REST API calls against the Yammer network and retrieving data for analysis. Currently, how I make Yammer REST API calls is through an App that I've created. I then generated the authentication token and then used this token in the REST API calls to get at the data.

What I'd really like to do now is to provide an app that allows me to call the REST API (using the same ETL tool) without the person installing the app to have to go through the rigmarole of generating the auth token.

I suppose one approach could be to use some JavaScript that displayed the token to the user so that they could then pass it on to us... Do you folks have any other suggestions as to how I might do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a recommended way to skip the OAuth authorization, but you can automate a lot of it away. I created [a Python script](https://gist.github.com/brianly/5080280) that uses the [YamPy](http://pythonhosted.org/yampy/index.html) library to acquire a token. It even fires up the browser to the correct URL for authorization. You should be able to do something similar with other languages.

Calling the [impersonation](https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/#a-impersonation) endpoint is another possibility. This will get you an OAuth token for another user so you'd need to have an app is just for producing OAuth tokens. It's probably a bit trickier to build right and secure than my script. Impersonation was designed for a specific category of app which means I don't recommend it by default. Even when it is a workable option it hides the authorization from end users which can potentially be a security issue, if say you app is compromised and handing out OAuth tokens. At least if the Yammer screen is in the way it's a bit more visible to the user what is happening.